# What APNS Certificate should I use

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

My company has commissioned the development of an application to one of its suppliers and they have published using their developer to account, this application must receive push notifications.
The company is doing a web service that will send a notification when this is invoked, We're using PushSharp and we need a certificate for sending notifications.
Now, my question is: The provider must give me a certificate or we can use one from our developer account (The company has one).?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cant use your production certificate , you need the apn certificate what they had used to publish. with that only you can able to push notification from server end.

Comment: Thanks @karthik, now we will request the certificate to our supplier.

Comment: request a valid production (push enabled) certificate. some times that will be revoked or expired.